# In C, How much memory my program waste?

Tags: c

I want to know, for example, I have a struct with three members...like:

```
struct Somethings { 
     int member1;
     int member2;
     char *member3;
}
```

And I do this:

```
  
struct Something thing = {1, 2, "I'm a sentence..."};
```

When I run my program, What I will have in memory? I means, will I have only a struct labeled 'thing' with theses values, or, will I have this struct and another copy of theses values in the code itself? I think that the compiler is smart enough to only have one copy of these values, in the struct, right? Someone knows any command to see it? I don't know debug very well...

Thanks.

Comment: What operating system and IDE are you using?

Comment: The *definition* of the structure is a compile-time entity -- it goes away during compilation. This is different than say, Java, which *keeps around class definitions*. Now, each `Something` *object* will "have its own memory" and `member3` may point to memory which is shared amongst these objects. -- There is a lot of questions in the post and I'm not sure exactly what is being asked, hopefully some of the above can lead to a more focused/refined question.

Comment: I'm using gcc, Thanks for your point.

Answer (score 2):

In practice, the answer to your question depends on exactly where you declare that line:

```
struct Something thing = {1, 2, "I'm a sentence..."};
```

At file scope, this declares `thing` with *static storage duration*, which means that it lives from program startup to program termination.  In this case, there is quite likely to be only one physical copy of the data, both in the compiled program on disk and in memory while the program executes.

Alternatively, within a function, this declares `thing` with *automatic storage duration*, which means that it lives only until the function returns.  In this case, there is still likely to be only one physical copy of the data in the compiled program, but while the program is executing there will be a second, temporary copy created each time the declaration of `thing` is reached, and destroyed each time that function returns.  (Note that this applies to the `1`, `2` and the pointer value stored in `thing.member3`, but not the string `"I'm a sentence..."` itself - there is still only ever one copy of that).  If the function is called recursively, then third, fourth, etc temporary copies of the data will be made.

Comment: It's exactly what I'm asking for, thanks for your answer, I was asking it because I'm afraid of about unnecessary memory waste. Can you explain it to me too > for example, if I declare it with static, Does matter where I am on my program, is it computed in compile time??? Thanks for your time

Comment: @drigoSkalWalker: Yes, if you declare it anywhere as `static` then it will have static storage duration, which in practice means only one copy of the data exists per definition (though be aware that if the definition is in a header file, there will be one definition for every file that includes that header).

Answer (score 0):

That statement will cause there to be somewhere in memory a sequence of bytes that looks something like this (assuming a [big-endian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Big-endian) processor and ignoring [structure padding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment) for simplicity's sake).

```
Location    Contents
   N          0x00    // highest byte of 1
   N+1        0x00   
   N+2        0x00
   N+3        0x01    // lowest byte of 1
   N+4        0x00    // highest byte of 2
   N+5        0x00
   N+6        0x00
   N+7        0x02    // loweest byte of 2
   N+8        0xLL    // Highest byte of pointer to pointing to location 0xLLMMNNPP
   N+9        0xMM    
   N+10       0xNN    
   N+11       0xPP    // Lowest byte of pointer pointing to 0xLLMMNNPP
```

And then at location `0xLLMMNNPP` you will have the string data:

```
   Location     Contents
   0xLLMMNNPP    0x49  // I
   0xLLMMNNPP+1  0x27  // '
   0xLLMMNNPP+2  0x6D  // m
   [and so on]
   0xLLMMNNPP+15 0x00  // the end-of-string terminator
```

In your program the structure doesn't really exist at all.  The structure only defines how the data is to be laid out in memory.  The compiler will remember that definition so it knows where to find the pieces of the structure given the start location of where structure data is sitting in memory.

Comment: The type of `member3` is `char *`.

Answer (score 0):

Definition of `struct Somethings` is how you tell the compiler about a new type you created.  `struct Something thing` is how you create an object of that type.

When the program runs, all the objects are created, and after their scope is exited, they are all destroyed.  For the objects you create using dynamic allocation, it is left to you, or the program exiting, to destroy the objects and release the memory held by them.

It should help if you look at the memory layout of a C program to understand the runtime foot print of a program.

And, the struct definition you have given in the question is not terminated properly.

Comment: Try using `objdumb -x program` to see what ends up in the executable binary of program.c.